# Change text size of a description in a compilationTemplate's relatedContent area

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

I'm trying to add a `description` to a `compilationTemplate`'s `itemBanner` in `relatedContent`.  My current template is as follows:

```
var Template = function() { return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <document>
        <compilationTemplate theme="light">
            <list>
                <relatedContent>
                    <itemBanner>
                        <heroImg src="${this.BASEURL}images/someImage.jpg" />
                        <description>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</description>
                    </itemBanner>
                </relatedContent>
                <header>
                    <title>Some Show</title>
                    <subtitle>Season 4</subtitle>
                    <row>
                        <text>Drama</text>
                        <text>5 Episodes</text>
                        <text>2015</text>
                    </row>
                </header>
                <section>
                    <listItemLockup>
                        <ordinal minLength="2">1</ordinal>
                        <title>A Danger to Himself and Others</title>
                        <decorationLabel>11:14</decorationLabel>
                    </listItemLockup>
                </section>
            </list>
        </compilationTemplate>
    </document>`
}
```

This does add text to the itemBanner where the `buttonLockup` items would normally exist, but the text is tiny.

[image: template]

How can I change the size and position of this `description` in the `itemBanner`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by adjusting the `font-size` attribute in the `style` tag:

```
<description style="tv-text-style: none; font-size:36; font-weight:regular;">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</description>
```

This doesn't wrap the text for you though.

[image: appletv]

I've asked a new question about the line wrapping here:

[Line Wrap description text in a compilationTemplate's relatedContent area in TVML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36556752/2415822)