# Line Wrap description text in a compilationTemplate's relatedContent area in TVML

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

How can I wrap the `description` text in the `relatedContent` area of a `compilationTemplate`?

[image: appletv]

My `description` tag:

```
<description style="tv-text-style: none; font-size:36; font-weight:regular; word-wrap:break-word;">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</description>
```

Full template:

```
var Template = function() { return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <document>
        <compilationTemplate theme="light">
            <list>
                <relatedContent>
                    <itemBanner>
                        <heroImg src="${this.BASEURL}images/shows/bates/BRANDHD2398_AEN_BATE_168121_TVE_000_2398_60_20160303_00_S3_REV_HD_1920x1080-16x9.jpg" />
                        <description style="tv-text-style: none; font-size:36; font-weight:regular; word-wrap:break-word;">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</description>
                    </itemBanner>
                </relatedContent>
                <header>
                    <title>Bates Motel</title>
                    <subtitle>Season 4</subtitle>
                </header>
                <section>
                    <listItemLockup>
                        <ordinal minLength="2">1</ordinal>
                        <title>A Danger to Himself and Others</title>
                        <decorationLabel>11:14</decorationLabel>
                    </listItemLockup>
                    < !-- ... -- >
                </section>
            </list>
        </compilationTemplate>
    </document>`
}
```

The text size changes, but the description truncates instead of wrapping to the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify pre-defined description area <del>with `min-height`, `max-height` styles?</del> with `tv-text-max-lines`. Example in https://github.com/iBaa/PlexConnectApp/blob/master/PlexConnectApp/TVMLTemplates/Fanart/Movie_PrePlay.xml, see `class description` and later usage.

(Edited 14Apr16 based on comment and double-check)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Like this?  `<description style="tv-text-style: none; font-size:36; font-weight:regular; word-wrap:break-word; min-height:50; max-height:100;">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit</description>`  I'm not seeing any change.

Comment: Yes, so were my thoughts - I know, I have done it earlier. Let me have a look, where/how...

Comment: Edited the answer.